# Not inserting correct values into MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, insert, mysqli

I'm having some trouble using MySQLi to insert values into a database. I don't get any errors, but the values being inserted are not correct at all. One of the TEXT fields is always empty, and the other one always has the value "ý". The INT field always contains the value 50396416. I am using utf8_general_ci.

```
CREATE TABLE events (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
    title TEXT NOT NULL ,
    content TEXT NOT NULL ,
    date INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
);
```

Here's what I have to insert the values:

```
function insertEvent($title, $content, $date) {

    $stmt = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO events (title, content, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?)');

    $stmt->bind_param('ssi', $title, $content, $date);
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->close();
}
```

It seems pretty simple, so I don't know what the problem could be. If you have any advice, I'd love to hear it!

I don't know if this could be a problem with my code, or with the database, because everything did work correctly on one server, but not on another.

#### Update

Actually I just noticed, through `phpinfo()`, that the servers seem to be using different MySQL versions. Could that possibly be causing the problem?

I'm also pretty sure that the data I'm using is correct. I'm getting the values from a form using `$_POST`. For example, if, for the "title" field, I enter "asdf":

```
$stmt->bind_param('ssi', $title, $content, $date);
$title = $_POST['title'];
echo $title; // echoes "asdf"
```

**It looks like it was just an incompatibility with the MySql version (4.something) on the server. I got them to update it, and it seems to work fine now.
Thanks everyone, for helping!**

Comment: Where does the data come from? Can you make test outputs using `echo`? What is the table's structure?

Comment: Using `echo` to see if the values are correct works fine. Is there a way to view the prepared statement with all the parameters?

Comment: Can you show an example of what an `echo` output gives you? As for the prepared statemtent, which engine are you using?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not exactly sure what you mean by the engine (I'm a bit of a noob at this).

Comment: well `50396416` is `1971-08-07 03:00:16 -0400` are you perhaps adding/subtracting time incorrectly to get this value - perhaps not supplying an argument to `time()`? As for the text are you sure your encoding is correct in the DB?

Comment: I'm not doing any adding or subtracting of time. As for the encoding, I'm using utf8_general_ci.

Comment: why are you saving date as INT and not DATETIME?

Comment: What versions are the servers in question?

Comment: Xorlev: 4.2 and 5.1. I got the web host to upgrade to the latest version of MySQL, and now it's working.

Answer (score 1):

Either use a debugger (e.g. [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) + [netbeans](http://netbeans.org/features/php/) as frontend) or add some more debug output.

```
echo "<pre>Debug: $stmt->bind_param('ssi', $title, $content, $date);\n</pre>";
$stmt->bind_param('ssi', $title, $content, $date);
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO events (title, content, date) VALUES ('?', '?', '?')");
```